# Inheriting from IndexedSeq, but want updated() to return child class

Tags: scala, inheritance

I'm using the RingBuffer implementation mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8878078/620178), which inherits from IndexedSeq:

```
class RingBuffer[A](val index: Int, val data: IndexedSeq[A]) extends IndexedSeq[A] {
  def shiftLeft = new RingBuffer((index + 1) % data.size, data)
  def shiftRight = new RingBuffer((index + data.size - 1) % data.size, data)
  def length = data.length
  def apply(i: Int) = data((index + i) % data.size)
}
```

What I want to be able to do is this:

```
var rb = new RingBuffer(0, IndexedSeq(1, 2, 3))
rb = rb.updated(0, 4).shiftLeft
```

... but updated returns an IndexedSeq.

Should I override updated in the RingBuffer implementation? Or is there a different approach I should take?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have a [CanBuildFrom](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom) for RingBuffer in implicit scope.  If you look at the full signature for `updated` in the [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.IndexedSeq), you'll see where CanBuildFrom is used:

```
def updated[B >: A, That](index: Int, elem: B)
                         (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[IndexedSeq[A], B, That])
                         : That
```

I suggest reading  Daniel Sobral's treatise in [Scala 2.8 breakOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout) for more details.

In general, I've found inheriting from most collections-library classes to be a mistake, or at least a lot harder than it would appear.