# Built-in method for rolling Scala List or Seq

Tags: list, scala

I'm trying to roll a list, for example like so:

```
val notRolled = (1 to 5).toList       // List(1,2,3,4,5)

val rolledBy1 = rollList(notRolled,1) // List(2,3,4,5,1)
val rolledBy2 = rollList(notRolled,2) // List(3,4,5,1,2)
val rolledBy3 = rollList(notRolled,3) // List(4,5,1,2,3)
val rolledBy4 = rollList(notRolled,4) // List(5,1,2,3,4)
val rolledBy5 = rollList(notRolled,5) // List(1,2,3,4,5)

val rolledByM1 = rollList(notRolled,-1) // List(5,1,2,3,4)
val rolledByM2 = rollList(notRolled,-2) // List(4,5,1,2,3)
val rolledByM3 = rollList(notRolled,-3) // List(3,4,5,1,2)
val rolledByM4 = rollList(notRolled,-4) // List(2,3,4,5,1)
val rolledByM5 = rollList(notRolled,-5) // List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I had a look at [scala-lang.org](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and can't seem to find anything that matches my requirement.

**Is there a built-in method for rolling a list?**

If not, is there a more efficient way to do it than this:

```
def rollList[T](theList: List[T], itemsToRoll: Int): List[T] = {
  val split = {
    if (itemsToRoll < 0) (theList.size + itemsToRoll % theList.size)
    else itemsToRoll % theList.size
  }
  val (beginning, end) = theList.splitAt(split)
  end ::: beginning
}
```

Comment: This question is a dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876769/best-practice-for-shifting-a-sequence-in-a-circular-manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the enrich-my-library pattern will allow you to add the `roll` method directly to all the collections so that you can call `myList.roll(2)`, as opposed to `roll(myList, 1)`.

Using the generic `CanBuildFrom` pattern allows you to make `roll` return the best possible type on these collections (so that `roll` on a `List` will return a `List`, but `roll` on an `Iterable` will return an `Iterable`).

All together, here is one option that abides by these patterns:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.TraversableLike

implicit class TraversableWithRoll[A, Repr <: Traversable[A]](val xs: TraversableLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  def roll[That](by: Int)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, That]): That = {
    val builder = bf()
    val size = xs.size
    builder.sizeHint(xs)
    val leftBy = if (size == 0) 0 else ((by % size) + size) % size
    builder ++= xs.drop(leftBy)
    builder ++= xs.take(leftBy)
    builder.result
  }
}
```

This allows you to do some of the following:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).roll(2) //List(4,5,1,2,3)
Seq(3, 4, 5).roll(-1) //Seq(5, 3, 4)
```

Notice the benefits of the fluent syntax enabled by the enrich-my-library pattern, and the stronger types enabled by the use of the `CanBuildFrom` implicit .

Comment: Nicely done! There is one problem, however, in that it throws an exception if you try to roll an empty collection (size == 0). Also I wonder if the `leftBy` calculation couldn't be simplified. This is what I came up with (there's probably better): `leftBy = ((by % size) + size) % size`

Comment: @jwvh Good catches, I've incorporated them into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of simulating a circular list in a functional way. I made it so that a positive `i` will do a right shift and a negative a left shift. This is the reverse of what the question has, but I felt it's more natural.

```
def shift[T](c: List[T], i: Int) = { 
   if(c.isEmpty) c
   else {
      val (h,t) = if (i >= 0) c.splitAt(c.size - i%c.size)
            else c.splitAt(- i%c.size) 
      t ++ h
   }
}
```

Here are some examples in the REPL:

```
cala> shift(List(1,2,4), 1)
res: List[Int] = List(4, 1, 2)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), 2)
res: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 1)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), 3)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), 4)
res: List[Int] = List(4, 1, 2)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), 5)
res: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 1)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), 6)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), -1)
res60: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 1)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), -2)
res: List[Int] = List(4, 1, 2)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), -3)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), -4)
res: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 1)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), -5)
res: List[Int] = List(4, 1, 2)

scala> shift(List(1,2,4), -6)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)
```

Comment: Fails for empty list.

Comment: @Shyamendra Solanki same as the OP's version, so obviously he's not intended to run it on empty lists or you want to "-1" OP's question too??

Comment: Good catch! just added a clause to support that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def rotate[A] (list: List[A], by: Int) = {
    if (list.isEmpty) list
    else {
        val shift = (by % list.size + list.size) % list.size
        val (l, r) = list.splitAt(shift)
        r ++ l
    }
}

val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
rotate(list, 1) // List(2, 3, 4, 5, 1)
rotate(list, 2) // List(3, 4, 5, 1, 2)
rotate(list, -1) // List(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
rotate(list, -2) // List(4, 5, 1, 2, 3)

rotate(list, -9) // List(2, 3, 4, 5, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my pure functional very simple proposition:

```
def circ[A]( L: List[A], times: Int ): List[A] = {

    if ( times == 0 || L.size < 2 ) L
    else circ(L.drop(1) :+ L.head , times-1)
}

val G = List("1a","2b","3c")

println( circ(G,1) ) //List(2b, 3c, 1a)
println( circ(G,2) ) //List(3c, 1a, 2b)
println( circ(G,3) ) //List(1a, 2b, 3c)
println( circ(G,4) ) //List(2b, 3c, 1a)
```

Added for times < 0 (rolling backwards):

```
def circ[A]( L: List[A], times: Int ): List[A] = {
    if ( times == 0 || L.size < 2 ) L
    else if ( times < 0 ) circ(L.reverse,-times).reverse 
    else                  circ(L.drop(1) :+ L.head , times-1)
}
```

Comment: reverse direction added

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
val notRolled = (1 to 5).toList
```

Let's say we want rotate with shift = 3

```
val shift = 3

notRolled.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._2 < shift).values.flatten.map(_._1)
```

For negative values we should add 5(lists size), so for shift = -3 we will calculate

```
val shift = -3
notRolled.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._2 < 2).values.flatten.map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to incorporate the ideas above, about CanBuildFrom, just as soon as I understand Scala better (!), but in the meantime, I had to do precisely this for the sake of writing a Burrows-Wheeler Transform algorithm. Here, with no `take()` or `drop()`, and no errors on empty collections (and, yes, side-effecting code):

```
def roll[A](xs: Traversable[A]): Iterator[Traversable[A]] = {
  var front = xs
  var back = collection.mutable.Buffer[A]()

  Iterator.continually(front ++ back).takeWhile { _ =>
    val done = front.isEmpty
    if (!done) {
      back :+= front.head
     front = front.tail
   }
   !done
  }
}
```