# How to add an element to List while making sure that list contains latest n elements in scala

Tags: list, scala

In Scala, what is the best way to add an element to a list while making sure that the list always contains latest n elements.

So if list is `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and n = 5, then adding 6 should result in `(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.

One possible way could be:

```
list = list ::: List(6)
list = list.takeRight(5)
```

Are there any better ways? Also, is there a better data-structure for maintaining such frequently changing collection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for shifting a sequence in a circular manner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876769/best-practice-for-shifting-a-sequence-in-a-circular-manner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a fixed size [Circular Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) would satisfy your need. I think apache commons provides some implementation.

A solution in scala using `List` could be:

```
scala> def dropHeadAndAddToList[T](obj: T, list: List[T]):List[T] = {
          list.drop(1) :+ obj
       }

       dropHeadAndAddToList: [T](obj: T, list: List[T])List[T]

scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> dropHeadAndAddToList(6, a)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: Imo, "addToList" doesn't sound like a good name for a function, which removes element from a list :)

Actually just "myList.drop(1) :+ 6" looks not so bad.

Comment: You're right, naming things is hard and my answer was lazy in this regard! I'll edit it to a better name :)

Comment: how does list.drop(1) compare with list.takeRight(n) performance wise?

Comment: scala> val time = System.currentTimeMillis; for (i <- 1 to 10000000) { list.takeRight(4) }; println(System.currentTimeMillis - time)
122
time: Long = 1443616699385

    scala> val time = System.currentTimeMillis; for (i <- 1 to 10000000) { list.drop(1) }; println(System.currentTimeMillis - time)
91
time: Long = 1443616709615

Comment: @TarunKumar microbenchmarking in the way you have shown is flawed, the recommended approach is to use [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).  Even still, [jmh has it's own flaws](http://bad-concurrency.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/the-uncanny-valley-of-l3-cache.html), so I would be wary of prematurely optimising such a (presumably) small part of the system, based on System.nanoTime calls in the repl.